# Images suddenly stop showing in my C#/WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a project that was working fine.

For some reason it stopped showing me the images I am using.

The images are located in a Resource File(.resx).

Maybe someone can help me understand what happen or tell me if this problem is only at my computer(and how I can solve it).

My project is located here and it requires VS2010:
https://favoriteorg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/favoriteorg/trunk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any localization?

Comment: No. But that what started it all. The code at the SVN(Revision 12) has no localization. At the meantime I continued editing the code and suddenly the images returned. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the meantime I continued editing the code and suddenly the images returned. I have no idea why